# Cannot filter data on server using Linq, EF Core, Npgsql, Postgres

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I tried to google a solution, as well as I read documentation.
So, I have trouble with filtering my entity this way:

```
// Raises the exception
MyUser myUser = _sqlContext.MyUsers
    .Where(user => user.UserLogin.ToLower() == userLogin.ToLower())
    .ToList()
    .FirstOrDefault();

// Raises the exception
MyUser myUser = _sqlContext.MyUsers
    .Where(user => user.UserLogin.ToLower() == userLogin.ToLower())
    .ToList()
    .FirstOrDefault();

// Raises the exception, too
MyUser myUser = _sqlContext.MyUsers
    .Where(user => user.UserLogin == userLogin)
    .FirstOrDefault();

// Raises the exception, too
MyUser myUser = _sqlContext.MyUsers
    .FirstOrDefault(user => user.UserLogin == userLogin);
```

I receive the following exception:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Where(p => p.UserLogin.ToLower() == __ToLower_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
> ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
> more information.

The list of users can be really big, so this in no option to call `ToList()` before `Where()` to force client-side filtering. In contrary, I need EF to build a query with WHERE, and return to client only filtered values.

My application uses ASP.NET Core 3.1 as well as EF Core 3.1.5. It doesn't work too if I remove ToLower().
How can I make this work?

UPD:
The problem is in custom getter/setter of user.UserLogin. Here Is the part of model:

```
public class MyUser
{
    internal string _userLogin { get; set; }

    public string UserLogin
    {
        get => _userLogin;
        set => _userLogin = value.ToLower();
    }
}
```

Comment: _sqlContext.MyUsers
    .Where(user => user.UserLogin.ToLower() == userLogin.ToLower()).AsQuerable() works.... but how to get the 1st element

Comment: Why use `ToLowe()`? Typically, databases use case-*in*sensitive collations. The last two queries *can't* throw the exception you posted as there's no call to `ToLower()`. If they threw, it was for a different reason

Comment: ToLower Is not a point. I updated my examples, basically I need something like _sqlContext.MyUsers
    .FirstOrDefault(user => user.UserLogin == userLogin); But this does not work

Comment: It *is* the point - the error complains that the query can't be translated. This happens when client-side functions are applied to properties, or if the properties don't actually map to table fields, like a calculated property. If the error you posted was caused by a bug in EF, it would mean that EF didn't work *at all*, for any query. Obviously, that's not the case.

Comment: Post your entities and your DbContext configuration. You should provide enough information to allow people to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete custom getter and setter as well as _userLogin field. So, the conclusion - there should be nothing except simple properties or fields inside Where or First(OrDefault) call.

Comment: That's not really true - EF Core doesn't care (or even knows) if your properties are auto-properties or not. But you really need to post a full code sample for us to understand what exactly you're doing.